# Avoid inherited styling inside List Section

Tags: swiftui, styling

When I add my custom widget into `List`'s `Section` `header`, the elements inside my widget gets styled. Among others all the text become ALLCAPS. How can I avoid that styling, especially text capitalization?

```swift
struct MyHeader: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello wOrLd!")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: MyHeader()) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct MyHeader: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello wOrLd!").textCase(.none)
    }
}
```

Maybe it works

Comment: It does, however other styling properties (font weight, different colors for dark/light mode, etc) are still affected. Is there a way to ignore all of that? All I want is a different background related to section headers, I don’t want any other styling.

Comment: I also can’t find a general method to handle it.